# clickTAG and stop tag won't work simultaneously

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cc, clicktag

I've created a swf banner and have added a stop(); action so it doesn't loop. As soon as I add the clickTAG to the file, the stop tag is ignored and continues to loop. I'm using Flash CC and as3. How do I get them both to work. I've done it before in older versions.

Here is my click tag:

```
    clickTAG.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onClick);
function onClick(e:MouseEvent):void {
    var click_url:String = root.loaderInfo.parameters.clickTAG;
    if(click_url) {
        navigateToURL(new URLRequest(click_url), '_blank');
    }
}
```

Here is my stop:

stop();

They are on different layers.

Answer (score 0):

Are you having some output in the "COMPILER ERRORS" panel?.

please note that the code must be inserted into Actions Frame at first Frame and that you must have a transparent movie clip in the Stage with "clickTAG" as instance name.

Comment: I'm getting an error 1120:Access of undefined property. Also, do I add the AS to the same layer as the movie clip

Comment: Hey lisa, could you upload a screenshot of your COMPILER ERRROS screen?